# Error during loading: Uncaught ReferenceError: jqxBaseFramework is not defined

Tags: karma-jasmine, jqxtreegrid, jqxtree

Error during loading: Uncaught ReferenceError: jqxBaseFramework is not defined in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js line 125124
getting this error in jasmin unit testing

switch (item) {

```
  case 'Add Privilage':
    selectedItem = this.myTree.getSelectedItem();
   // document.getElementById("Update").click();
    if (selectedItem != null) {
      this.selectedParentName = selectedItem.label;
      this.selectedParentUId = selectedItem.value.privilegeId;
      this.showAddPrivilageDiv = true;
      // this.myTree.addTo({ label: 'Item' }, selectedItem.element);
    }
```